# How to deploy Meteor (Android) app to GoDaddy (or other) server/host

Tags: meteor

I am a complete Meteor noob and was wondering how to deploy my application to a GoDaddy host. My app will be deployed as an Android app.

I've reviewed the Meteor deployment guide at http://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#deploying but it doesn't really seem to provide specific steps on how to deploy to a different host.

1. Has anyone had experience deploying a Meteor application to GoDaddy? and if so, could you provide steps? Can I FTP my Meteor files to the GoDaddy server and run meteor from there? (I apologize for the simplistic view)
2. Also, in general, how does deployment work when you deploy to a different host/server? Does the MongoDB database also get ported to that server?
3. Along the same lines as #2, if my app is hosted on GoDaddy (or some other server), how will this affect how my Meteor Android app access things like the MongoDB database?

Again, I apologize for the noob questions. I have used more traditional web hosting options using FTP, PHP API's and SQL databases but this is quite different so I wanted to understand how deploying a Meteor app to a different host actually works.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Meteor UpX, I've seen people use it to successfully deploy to DigitalOcean, and GoDaddy won't be much different.

https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx